# Display array in question label and button label

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I have an array of questions and 3 answers and i want to display the question in the text label and the three answers in each button label. The text label and each button have an outlet. Im a begginer at swift and im having trouble extracting from the array

```
struct Questions {

    let allQuestions = [

        "The easiest way to learn is:",
        "When buying clothes i usually make the decision on the basis of:"
]

    let answers = [

        [
            "By viewing, reading, and observing how the others carry out certain tasks",
            "By listening, discussing and doing according to verbal instructions",
            "By doing and experimenting by myself",
        ],

        [
            "By their appearance and looks",
            "Their practicality and use",
            "How comfortable they are or how they feel"
        ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Initialise your struct
var questions = Questions()

//Keep track of what question you're on. Update this when you reload view
var questionNumber: Int = 0

//Add buttons to outlet collection
@IBOutlet var answerButtons: [UIButton]!

//Populating a question is simple
let aQuestion = questions.allQuestions[questionNumber]
yourQuestionLabel.text = "\(aQuestion)"

//For answers, loop through buttons outlet collection
for x in 0..<questions.answers[questionNumber].count {
    answerButton[x].titleLabel?.text = "\(questions.answers[questionNumber][x])"
}
```

Comment: I think im missing something, because when i run the code, the question function works perfectly, but the answers aren't changing. I already put the function inside the viewdidload but the answers still aren't changing